# How to get UI objects to only appear in dialog AFTER button is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

1. I have a dialog that initially has several buttons, let's call them Write, View, OK, and Cancel.
2. The way it should to is to have the dialog upon creation ***only*** have those three buttons and nothing more.
3. When the Write button is cancelled, it's supposed to create a `QLineEdit` object in the window above the buttons where the user can enter a new string,which when OK is then clicked will be added to an external `QStringList`.
4. When View is clicked, **LineEdit** should go away (if it's up) and a **QListView** to come up instead to view everything in that list.
5. The problem is, I know how to use `hide()` to get objects that are already in the dialog to NOT appear.
6. but I am having trouble figuring out how to get an object not currently on the table to appear. I'm new to using Qt so it may be something easy I'm just accidentally overlooking (in fact I hope it is).

   Could anyone please offer advice? Thanks!

Comment: You can set the item to already be in the dialog but start out hidden.

Comment: Right, that's how I have it now, but how do I get them to show up when I need them?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the items normally and then set:

```
ui->control->setVisible(false);
```

after you have created the UI (after `ui->setupUi(this);`) possibly in the constructor (in case you use code generated by Qt Creator).

And when you need them:

```
ui->control->setVisible(true);
```

Doc for this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#visible-prop

Answer (score 0):

when using a `QListView` you should also have a `QListModel` that provides the data to it, if you only have `QStrings` then a [`QStringListModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstringlistmodel.html) is premade for you to use

to add a row you can do:

```
int rows = model->rowCount();
model->addRow(rows,1);
QModelIndex index = model->index(rows,0);
model->setData(index, string);
```